# creating an array using find method in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, hash

```
input = {"color"=>["red"],"size"=>["s","l"]}

json_obj = [{"color":"red","id":"123","size":"s","name":"test"},
            {"color":"yellow","id":"124","size":"s","name":"test"},
            {"color":"red","id":"125","size":"l","name":"test"}]
```

Output should be

```
output["red_s"] = {"color":"red","id":"123","size":"s","name":"test"}
output["red_l"] = {"color":"red","id":"125","size":"l","name":"test"}
```

output is the combinations of the input and a find on the json_obj.
How to get the output in rails?

I have the below script to get the combinations ie.red_s and red_l,

```
ary = input.map {|k,v| [k].product v}
output = ary.shift.product(*ary).map {|a| Hash[a]}
```

And

```
output[red_s]=json_obj.find{|h| h["color"] == "red" and h["size"] == "S"}
```

I don't want to have any hardcodings in code like color and size as above.

Comment: i don't understand your question very well, but i suppose you want to be using `group_by` on your `json_obj` array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should get you close to what you want.
Note the "ticks" around your json array object (what you had is not valid ruby)
The other issue is you would have to figure a better way to create the output hash key.

```
require 'json'
input = {"color"=>["red"],"size"=>["s","l"]}
output = {}

json_obj = '[{"color":"red","id":"123","size":"s","name":"test"},
            {"color":"yellow","id":"124","size":"s","name":"test"},
            {"color":"red","id":"125","size":"l","name":"test"}]'

found = JSON.parse json_obj
input.each_key do |key|
  found = found.select { |item| input[key].include?(item[key]) }
end
puts found

found.each do |item|
  output_key = ""
  input.each_key do |key|
    output_key = "#{item[key]}_" + output_key
  end
  output["#{output_key}"] = item.to_json
end


puts output
```

Comment: Thanks. The output i see is {"s_red_"=>"{\"color\":\"red\",\"id\":\"123\",\"size\":\"s\",\"name\":\"test\"}", "l_red_"=>"{\"color\":\"red\",\"id\":\"125\",\"size\":\"l\",\"name\":\"test\"}"} whereas, i want the key as "red_s"

Comment: input should be {"color"=>["red"],"size"=>["s","l"]} only and not  {"size"=>["s", "l"], "color"=>["red"]}

Comment: Its ok to change to {"size"=>["s", "l"], "color"=>["red"]}. I will have it this way. Or output_key = output_key + "_" + item["attr"][key]  also helps keeping the same input.